# Why is a Redux reducer called a reducer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, functional-programming

Whilst learning Redux I've come across reducers. The documentation states:

> The reducer is a pure function that takes the previous state and an action, and returns the next state. (previousState, action) => newState. It's called a reducer because it's the type of function you would pass to Array.prototype.reduce(reducer, ?initialValue) .

MDN describes the `reduce` method as:

> The reduce() method applies a function against an accumulator and each value of the array (from left-to-right) to reduce it to a single value.

I'm still confused on why the Redux definition of a reducer as it's making no sense. Secondly the MDN description doesn't seem correct either. The `reduce` method isn't always used to reduce to a single value. It can be used in place of `map` and `filter` and is actually faster when used in place of chaining.

Is the MDN description incorrect?

Jumping back to the Redux definition of a reducer, it states:

> It's called a reducer because it's the type of function you would pass to Array.prototype.reduce(reducer, ?initialValue)

I'm under the impression that a reducer in Redux is responsible for modifying state. An example reducer:

```
const count = function(state, action) {
    if(action.type == 'INCREMENT') {
        return state + 1;
    } else if(action.type == 'DECREMENT') {
        return state - 1;
    } else {
        return state;
    }
}
```

I don't see how this is a function that would be passed to `reduce`. How is that data being reduced to a single value? If this is a function you would pass to `reduce` then `state` would be the callback and `action` would be the initial value.

Comment: To me, coming from WPF and C#, actions seem to be athe "setter" action and reducers are the "getter" action.  While not actually functioning this way under the hood because it returns a completely new state object instead of changing it, but the end result is similar to what it accomplishes.

Comment: As a developer with over 15 years of experience in Java, .NET, Android, Angular, PHP, and other stacks, I can for sure say that namings in redux are simply a disgrace to the development community. Redux developers should be ashamed of themselves for confusing generations of developers.

Comment: Regarding your challenge of the MDN definition, can you provide an example where a `reducer` does not return a single value? Remember that an Array is still a single value. Certainly `reduce` can be used in place of `map`/`filter`, but it's different in that you're working off of one value (the accumulator) instead of operating on each element in isolation.

Comment: Regarding your 2nd to last paragraph, the entire reducer function gets passed as the "reducer" - the "initial value" is a separate parameter.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

The term "reduce" is actually a functional term used in functional programming. In a language like Haskell, F# or even JavaScript, we define a transformation that takes a collection (of any size) as input and returns a single value as output.

So (not to be pedantic, but I find this helps me) think of it visually. We have a collection:

```
[][][][][][][][][][]
```

...which we want to collapse into a single value:

```
N
```

Programming functionally, we would do this with a single function that we could call recursively on each element of the collection. But if you do that, you need to keep track of the intermediate value somewhere, right? Non-pure implementations might keep some kind of "accumulator" or variable outside of the function to keep track of the state, like so:

```
var accumulator = 0;
var myArray = [1,2,3,4,5];

myArray.reduce(function (each) {
    accumulator += 0;
});

return accumulator;
```

With pure functions, though, we can't do this - because by definition, pure functions can't have effects outside of their function scope. Instead of relying on an external variable that encapsulates our "state" between calls, we simply pass the state along in the method:

```
var myArray = [1,2,3,4,5];

return myArray.reduce(function (accumulator, each) {
    return accumulator + each;
}, 0);
```

In this case we call the function a "reducer" because of its method signature. We have `each` (or `current` - any name is fine), representing an object in the collection; and `state` (or `previous`), which is passed to each iteration of the function, representing the results of the transformation we've already done to the previous elements in the collection.

Note that the MDN documentation you referenced is correct; the `reduce()` function always does return a single value. In fact, the `reduce` method in any language is a [higher-order function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function) that takes a "reducer" (a function with the method signature defined above) and returns a single value. Now, yes, you *can* do other stuff with it, if your function that you call has side effects, but you shouldn't. (Essentially, don't use `.reduce()` as a foreach.) Even if the method you call with `reduce` has side effects, the *return value* of reduce itself will be a single value, not a collection.

The cool thing is, this pattern doesn't just have to apply to arrays or concrete collections, as you've seen in React; this pattern can be applied to streams as well, since they're pure functions.

Hope this helps. For what it's worth, the definition on the Redux site could be improved (as the concept of a reducer isn't just because of Javascript's Array prototype method). You should submit a PR!

Edit: There's a Wikipedia article on the subject. Note that reduce has different names, and in functional languages, it's commonly known as Fold. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)#Folds_as_structural_transformations

Edit (2020-10-03): People still seem to be finding this useful - that's good. With time, I've realized that "fold" is a much better term for this; the functional languages got it right. "Reducer" isn't really a bad term, but it's not necessarily a good one, either.

Comment: "the return value of reduce itself will be a single value, not a collection." --- this needs re-wording. There is nothing wrong in returning a collection. Fold is a more powerful operation than any other collection-based so you can express everything else with just it.

Comment: @zerkms Ehh, yeah, I suppose you're right. You could return a "collection", but...hmm. Wonder what a good way to word that is. I suppose you're returning the final state of the full transformation, which is "one" state.

Comment: It's folding :-) `(a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b` --- here is a signature from haskell. So the return type `b` can be anything, including `[a]`. So for that very reason I slightly don't like the term "reducer", since it never changes the shape of the state (it can but only crazy would do that).

Comment: @zerkms Feel free to edit the question, if you think that you can add valuable information and teach the concept well. I think it's good to tie into the OP's question about the "reducer" terminology, though. If your edit is substantial, I'll make this a community wiki.

Comment: @zerkms I've been thinking about a better way to describe this. Do you think it's accurate to say that you can "build a return value" (regardless of type - an atom or a collection) based on an existing set?

Comment: I'm not sure. The variable/binding with a result is often called "an accumulator". But using "to accumulate" there looks awkward. Just leave it as is, and these comments would be a clarification :-)

Comment: i think its same as semi-automatic washing machine vs automatic washing machine , in first we have to maintain its state for drying the clothes but in another be get the result output it maintain its state internally.

Comment: Interesting. Still strange that Redux reducers receives 2 params, with different meanings. The concept would fit more if those 2 params were similar to "reduce" something into another "thing". Another point yet is that it is nothing special to return a "single value", in OOP thats common in most functions... another one yet, the function sum(a, b) { return a + b; } would fit in the "reducer" definition. Something that old and basic, deserving a new naming, is a bit estrange. In my opinion, all the Redux naming is misguiding and too forced.

Comment: By any chance do you know when the term "reduce" was first used and in which language? If I figure it out before someone else answers I'll post it back here. I would love to be able to point to a historical moment in time when the term "fold" was first misrepresented as "reduce" so that we can first explain when it was incorrectly (IMO) renamed to "reduce", and then continue to explain the "fold" pattern instead of the "reduce" pattern.

Comment: As a developer with over 15 years of experience in Java, .NET, Android, Angular, PHP, and other stacks, I can for sure say that namings in redux are simply a disgrace to the development community. Redux developers should be ashamed of themselves for confusing generations of developers.

Comment: I agree with Saeed Neamati.  This is pretty horrible.  The term "reduce" makes sense when used for its original purpose (i.e. aggregation), but it doesn't make sense to apply to functions which don't aggregate, but just take a single value and transform into a new value.  React's explanation that reducers "reduce a set of actions (over time) into a single state" is an absurd attempt to try to make the term fit.

Answer (score 24):

> The reason why a [redux reducer](https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers) is called a `reducer` is because you could "reduce" a `collection of actions` and an `initial state` (of the store) on which to perform these actions to get the resulting `final state`.

How? To answer that, let me define a reducer again:

> The [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method applies a `function (reducer)` against an `accumulator` and each
>   value of the array (from left-to-right) to reduce it to a single
>   value.

And what does a redux reducer do?

> The reducer is a pure `function` that takes the current state and an
>   action, and returns the next state. Note that the state is `accumulated` as each action on the collection is applied to change this state.

So given a `collection of actions`, the reducer is applied on each value of the collection (from left-to-right). The first time, it returns the `initial value`. Now the reducer is applied again on this initial state and the first action to return the next state. And the next collection item (action) is applied each time on the `current state` to get the `next state` until it reaches the end of the array. And then, you get `the final state`. How cool is that!

Comment: Best explanation... I still think its a terrible name to use though... the store is not a true functional accumulator in the traditional sense, its more complicated than that. StoreModifier seems better =)

Answer (score 16):

Calling Redux reducers *reducers* is semantically incorrect and doesn't make much sense.
That's why the author is confused.

A reducer is *a function that **reduces a set of values** to a single value*.
We can also say that it *folds the values* - thus the classic `fold()` fn in functional programming.

Since Redux reducer *does not* fold a set of value, but applies an action to a state and always returns the same shape (`State -> Action -> State`) - it should be called *applicator* or *applier*.
But, since we have to always return the same *shape* of the state, and not just smth completely unrelated - we'd make much more sense calling Redux state applicators - *changers*, *transformers* or *mutators*.
And, it has indeed become commonplace to use terms like *'mutate the state'* and *'state mutator'*.

But Redux sounds just so much cooler, than *Applux* or *Mutux* :)

Comment: What a wonderful answer.  Thanks for this. Reducer isn't an accurate name - but as you said - Applux, Mutux would sound horrible. Appropriate naming convention and marketing don't go together,  I guess!

Comment: Can we downvote the Redux documentation? I've spent at least 15 minutes researching this because the name didn't make prima facie sense.

Answer (score 15):

Sorry, but I would disagree with previous answers. I **would not** support the naming `reducer`. I'm passionate about FP and immutability. Don't blame me, read the second part, but I want to state first, why I disagree.

It's correct that the reducers are the sequence of transformations, but the sequence itself - could be part of another sequence. Imagine it, like links - a part of chain. But the chain itself could be part of longer chain. Each link is the "transition" of the global state. Than, what the theory behind it?

Isn't it actually the "Finite state machine"? - close, but not. It's actually the [Transition system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transition_system).

> A labelled transition system is a tuple (S, Λ, →) where S is a set of states, Λ is a set of labels and → is a set of labelled transitions

So, `S` - are set of our states

`Λ` - is our so-called "actions" (but *labels* in theory)

... and

`→` - <s>reducers</s> "labelled transitions"! I would name it so, if I am creator of this library.

Understanding this theory helped me to implement my library, where I can have **low-level transition system** as a part of **high-level transition system** (like chain - still could be part of longer chain) - and still having single global Redux state.

Comment: I've been struggling with the library simply because I just can't get pass the 'reducer' nomenclature... it's actually helpful for me to know that others struggle with the name as well. @code4kix definition above also helped

Answer (score 7):

> I'm under the impression that a reducer in Redux is responsible for modifying state. An example reducer:

```
const count = function(state, action) {
    if (action.type == 'INCREMENT') {
        return state + 1;
    } else if (action.type == 'DECREMENT') {
        return state - 1;
    } else {
        return state;
    }
}
```

> ... I don't see how this is a function that would be passed to reduce. How is that data being reduced to a single value? If this is a function you would pass to reduce then state would be the callback and action would be the initial value.

```js
// count function from your question
const count = function (state, action) {
    if (action.type == 'INCREMENT') {
        return state + 1;
    } else if (action.type == 'DECREMENT') {
        return state - 1;
    } else {
        return state;
    }
}

// an array of actions
const actions =
  [ { type: 'INCREMENT' }
  , { type: 'INCREMENT' }
  , { type: 'INCREMENT' }
  , { type: 'INCREMENT' }
  , { type: 'DECREMENT' }
  ]

// initial state
const init = 0
  
console.log(actions.reduce(count, init))
// 3 (final state)
// (INCREMENT 4 times, DECREMENT 1 time)
```

Answer (score 4):

These answers are good but I think it's much simpler than you think. I'll admit that I had a similar confusion at first. The reduce method on Javascript arrays takes an accumulator and a callback function.

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3]
const sum = arr.reduce((accumulator, element) => {
  accumulator += element;
  return accumulator;
}); // sum equals 6 now
```

The reason it's called a reducer in redux is because it roughly has a similar structure.

```
const sum = arr.reduce((accumulator, element) => {  // accumulator is the initial state
  accumulator += element; // we do something to modify the initial state
  return accumulator;  // we return that and it becomes the new state
});
```

So every time we run a reducer we take something in, modify it, and return a copy of that same thing. On each iteration we're pointing to the same thing. Ok, yes, we have to make a copy in redux so as to not directly modify state, but symbolically every time we run it, it's kind of like the way reduce starts with an initial state in the example above of 1. Then we add 2 to our inital state and return 3. Now we run our 'reducer' again with an intial state of 3 and add 3 and we end up with 6.

Answer (score 3):

> It's called a reducer because it's the type of function you would pass to Array.prototype.reduce(reducer, ?initialValue)

[Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

This is very similiar to what you would pass to Array.reduce as the callback (reducer). The important part being:

```
callback
  Function to execute on each value in the array, taking four arguments:
    previousValue
      The value previously returned in the last invocation of the callback, or initialValue, if supplied. (See below.)
    currentValue
      The current element being processed in the array.
```

Where state is the "previousValue" and action is the "currentValue".

Answer (score 3):

Both `Array.reduce` and Redux take a "reducer" function, which reduces `previous` and `current` into a single `return` value.

```js
const reducer = (previous, current) => {
  /* calculate value */
  return value;
};
```

|  | previous | current | return |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Array.reduce | accumulator | current element | new accumulator |
| Redux | state | action | new state |

---

[Redux docs](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-2-concepts-data-flow#:%7E:text=Detailed%20Explanation%3A%20Why%20Are%20They%20Called%20%27Reducers%3F%27):

> If we were to create an array of Redux actions, call `reduce()`, and
> pass in a reducer function, we'd get a final result the same way:
>
> ```
> const actions = [
>   { type: 'counter/incremented' },
>   { type: 'counter/incremented' },
>   { type: 'counter/incremented' }
> ]
>
> const initialState = { value: 0 }
>
> const finalResult = actions.reduce(counterReducer, initialState)
> console.log(finalResult)
> // {value: 3}
> ```
>
> We can say that **Redux reducers reduce a set of actions (over time)
> into a single state**. The difference is that with `Array.reduce()` it
> happens all at once, and with Redux, it happens over the lifetime of
> your running app.

Comment: I like this answer because it visually (in a table) compares the method signatures of `Array.reduce` and the Redux notion of `reduce`, which is the key similarity for the naming convention.

Comment: Also:  This answer gives a link to the Redux docs which now thoroughly discuss this question.  Excellent.

Answer (score 2):

It's a confusing name because in practice it has nothing to do with `Array.prototype.reduce`.

In the Redux source code [here](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/bc53cd00a46f149b760e6f6690d6a95208e64dc3/src/createStore.ts#L246), this is how your reducer is called:

```js
currentState = currentReducer(currentState, action)
```

It's enticing to use the term because your state at any point in time *could* be found by calling `arrayOfPreviousActions.reduce(reducer)`.

```js
['INCREMENT', 'INCREMENT'].reduce((currentState, action) => currentState++, 0)
```

But it's not actually called like this.

---

The real question is what would be a better name for this?

If we don't consider the output/purpose, it's handling an action/event. An `actionHandler`, `actionProcessor`.

*Aside: `event` is probably a better term than `action` too because Redux is often also used to respond to API responses which results in action types set to `GET_USERS_SUCCESS`...which is clearly an event. This was simply adopted from Flux though.*

Redux draws inspiration from the [Event Sourcing](https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html) pattern and State Machines/Transition Systems. Googling around revealed the term `state transition` often used.

> state transitions can be represented as functions that take a state and an event, and produce a new state

But what do we call these "functions"?

IMHO, `reducer` is a poor name because it doesn't encode any meaning about its purpose, just what it looks like, but I can't think of a better one.

In the end, all names for things were invented at some point, and given its popularity, `reducer` is now associated with `state reducer` or `state transition function`.

Just look at the origin of the term `argument` for example:

> The use of the term "argument" developed from astronomy, which historically used tables to determine the spatial positions of planets from their positions in the sky. These tables were organized according to measured angles called arguments, literally "that which elucidates something else."

Answer (score 0):

It's not a very specific name, but the reducer in Redux does the same thing that other reducer functions do. They take in multiple things and give us back one thing. The Redux reducer takes in two things (the previous state and an action to be performed on that previous state) and reduce those two things down to one: the next state.